# How to fill up Tapestry5 palette with list coming from web service?

Tags: java, web-applications, tapestry, palette

I am trying to fill up Palette component in Tapestry 5 with result of calling web service, which is a Segment list. Segment is a ordinary class with some attributes like title... I would like to display title as an item in Available, Selected lists of Palette.
What I have found so far was examples of using the enum as a class, but that's not my case, is it? Can anybody help me with this issue? I basically don't know how to map those titles from Segment into the model of Palette. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`SelectModel`](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/SelectModel.html) and pass it to the `model` parameter. As the documentation for the parameter says

> Model used to define the values and labels used when rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, eventually I have solved that using probably easiest implementation possible by looking at this official guide:
http://tapestry.apache.org/using-select-with-a-list.html